# Getting this error while reading excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have code

```
string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" + strSheetPath + @";DriverId=1046;FIL=excel 12.0;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;";
 //string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strSheetPath +";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
string destinationConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KGD6DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string query = "Select * From [Sheet1$]";

using (var myConnection = new OleDbConnection(conn))
using (var destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationConnectionString))
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
{
    //Map first column in source to second column in sql table (skipping the ID column).
    //Excel schema[CompanyName,Phone] Table schema[ShipperID, CompanyName, Phone]
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 1);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 2);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 3);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 4);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 5);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(5, 6);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(6, 7);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(7, 8);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(8, 9);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(9, 10);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(10, 11);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(11, 12);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(12, 13);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(13, 14);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(14, 15);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(15, 16);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(16, 17);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(17, 18);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(18, 19);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(19, 20);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(20, 21);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(21, 22);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(22, 23);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(23, 24);

    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.sampleInventory";

    using (var myCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        destinationConnection.Open();

        var myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(myReader);
        }
    }
}
return (new DataTable());
```

getting error on connection opening line.

Error:
**Could not find installable ISAM.**

Comment: You do not have an error; you have an exception. Put a try/catch block around the whole thing; then in the catch block, get the value of ex.ToString() and post that here.

Comment: This is the same line that i got. When I try to catch the inner exception then it is giving me object reference null exception.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are building 32 bit application, otherwise is shouldn't work because Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is only for x86 platforms

If this doesn't help go to the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805

Comment: Ok, but how come i know i am building  32 bit application?? steps please

Comment: For C# projects, you will find this option on the Project Properties dialog under the build tab.  For VB.net projects, the setting is found on the Advanced Compiler Settings dialog which is made available via the Advanced Compile Options button on the Compile tab of the Project Properties.  The list of available options are:

1. Any CPU 
2. x86
3. x64

If you would like to see all available "processor architecture" download the following extension: 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879

Answer (score 0):

It looks like perhaps the component that allows Excel data to be queried as a database is missing or incorrectly registered on your machine.

There are some instructions at this link that may help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805